# Unix : Running Processes in Parallel : 2 Instances only

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

My `/tmp` directory can have hundreds of files. I want to transfer them to another server but only two FTP instances should be run.

I created one FTP script, which takes input variable as file name and starts the `trfr` process.

Main Script: Process to create a list file and then created two variables , `var1` and `var 2` which takes first two file names.

I created a while loop and ran `ksh ftp.sh var1 & ksh ftp.sh var2`

Issue:

If `var1` job is running , I cant run `var2` again as command will not come out of the while loop.

Comment: Kind of hard to resolve this without you adding the relevant part of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using GNU Parallel, like this:

```
cd /tmp
parallel -j 2 trfr {} ::: *
```

The `-j 2` makes only two run at once, and all the filenames are given after the `:::`. If that overflows your command line, you can use `find` or `ls` like this:

```
cd /tmp
find . -print0 | parallel -0 -j 2 trfr {}
```

Comment: I am not not sure abt GNU Parallel...Let me do some more investigation

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this. First generate a list of all the files and sort it by size, so that each of your FTP processes is sending similarly sized files and one doesn't take longer than the other, then start two FTPs and wait for both to finish till all files have been transferred.

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp

# Generate list of all files sorted into increasing size
du * | sort -n | cut -f 2- | \
    while :; do
       read f
       [ $? -eq 1 ] && break
       echo $f
       trfr "$f" &
       read f
       [ $? -eq 1 ] && break
       echo $f
       trfr "$f" &
       wait           # for both transfers to finish
    done
```